# How to update crashlytics to fabric in cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

HI i am working in a cordova based application in that i need to add crashlytics in android platform so i used the following plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin.git --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_SECRET=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API SECRET HERE --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API KEY HERE
```

it working fine but in the crashlytics dashboard it shows a warning message like

```
Outdated SDK: We've made improvements to the Crashlytics SDK. Please update to the latest using the Fabric plugin.
```

How can i update the plugin with fabric?Thanks in advance

Comment: try with this plugin [link](https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin)

Comment: @Anil Thanks a lot. But this is not working for me

Comment: I don't think there is a way of installing crashlytics with a plugin that uses the SDK, you'll have to follow the steps on fabric page and install it as any native project (opening the project on eclipse or android studio)

Comment: no i used this plugin and the app added to crashlytics successfully cordova plugin add https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin.git --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_SECRET=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API SECRET HERE --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API KEY HERE
 the only problem is showing the warning message

Answer (score 2):

There is now a plugin to use the Fabric SDK. I didn't try but it seems to be what you were looking for : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fabric-plugin